# Why doesn't Visual Studio mark it as an error when I implement an abstract method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, abstract

Why does this compile?

```
public abstract class Thing
{
    public abstract void ActualWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this should be impossible to execute");
    }
}
```

Shouldn't `abstract` methods disallow implementation, as they will by necessity be implemented later?

Visual Studio didn't mark it as an error, as per CodeCamper's comment. Strange to me as it didn't lock up per se, it still noticed other errors just not that one.

Comment: Sometimes the IDE locks up and does not visually update when an error occurs or is fixed for a variety of reasons. Usually I just hit the run button regardless of what it says(unless the error is a real one) in order for it to update and show me the real issues.

Comment: If true, this would be strange. Are you sure the method itself (and not just the class) is marked as `abstract`? What compiler are you using, csc or msc (or possibly some other one)? What version?

Comment: Visual Studio didn't mark it as an error, as per CodeCamper's comment.
Strange to me as it didn't lock up per se, it still noticed other errors just not that one. Is this really worth down voting? I'm happy to delete this question then

Comment: Well I was going to vote to close it as well, but I don't think any of the reasons for closing applied. Also CodeCamper, if you could add to your answer that the IDE simply didn't register it, I think your answer would be more complete, as it addressing my problem more directly.

Comment: Nacht I added instructions on how to reproduce your situation via typing Abstract manually afterwards thereby producing a no error situation until you attempt to compile.

Comment: @Nacht, the question as originally written was difficult to help, but your elaboration has made it a good question! :)

Comment: Cool, thanks guys :) Glad to turn a bad question into a good one

Comment: Anytime, tried to up vote you but it would only let me do it once. Hopefully it is a matter of minutes till it turns positive.

Comment: Removed -1... consider updating title so it is clear that it is not "compile" but rather VS error highlighting while you type .

Comment: yeah i was thinking about changing the title, wasnt sure if it was possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes the Visual Studio IDE simply is not able to register an error until it is refreshed such as by attempting to run the program. A perfect example take the code below then manually add the words Abstract after both "public"s and it will not immediately register as an error. This is just a glitch in Visual Studio.

```
public class Thing
    {
        public void ActualWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this should be impossible to execute");
        }
    }
```

Even though it shows no error once you run the program you will get the following error:

> Error 1   ... cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract

Why does this compile? It doesn't. Visual Studio and probably many other IDEs have problems registering errors on the fly depending on how you type them out.

MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.71).aspx)

> Because an abstract method declaration provides no actual implementation, there is no method
>   body; the method declaration simply ends with a semicolon and there are no braces ({ })
>   following the signature.

Comment: perhaps this has something to do with it being a semantic error rather than syntactic?

Comment: It definitely has to do with the fact that you can put a non abstract method in an abstract class. So when it sees the brackets VS is not smart enough to realize it is pertaining to an abstract method.

Comment: heh ok. i guess it's just a bug and that's all there is to it

Answer (score 3):

This does not compile:

Error:'cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract'